# Not sure if I need to re-import scss files

Tags: css, sass

Here's my `main.scss` file with all my imports.

```
/* Pages */
@import"pages/about";
@import"pages/contact";
@import"pages/home";
@import"pages/projects";

/* Partails */
@import "partials/gridmixins";
@import "partials/mixins";
@import "partials/colors";
@import "partials/typography";

/* Libs */
@import "bower_components/modular-scale/stylesheets/modular-scale";
@import "bower_components/normalize-scss/normalize";
```

Now let's say I want to use `modular-scale` inside of the `_home.scss` partial. Do I need to `@import "bower_components/modular-scale/stylesheets/modular-scale";`inside of `_home.scss`? to use the `modular-scale` functions?

I'm quite sure I'm correct as I tried to use some of my `typography` variables inside of `_home.scss` earlier and was thrown a error that my variable could not be found. This was due to **not** importing my `typography` partial.

Just seems kind of redundant to keep importing the files I want to use if I have already imported them once into `main.scss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable or a function on a another partial file, you need import first the file contain this variable/function.

Like that:

```
/* Libs */
@import "bower_components/modular-scale/stylesheets/modular-scale";
@import "bower_components/normalize-scss/normalize";

/* Pages */
@import"pages/about";
@import"pages/contact";
@import"pages/home";
@import"pages/projects";

/* Partails */
@import "partials/gridmixins";
@import "partials/mixins";
@import "partials/colors";
@import "partials/typography";
```